# How to set an image dynamically on UICollectionView section header?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have an `UICollectionView` with a custom header. I have an `ImageView` and a `label` on the header view. I want to change the ImageView's image when I'm selecting an item from UICollectionView? Is it possible to do? If it is how can I do it?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is possible, this is a way to do it

First set your image as IBOutlet (will asume headerImage)
Then implement the didSelectItem method

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    self.headerImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"newImage.png"]; 
}
```

Comment: My header is a custom header. It's IBOutlet is in another class. Cannot get it on collection view class

Comment: How are you adding the custom header to the view? Is a class that you wrote?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to hold a reference to the image view, and then change the image in the following function (part of the UICollectionView's Delegate protocol)

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: Its a big tricky, you have to register your header view class with the UICollectionView, and then it works similar to UICollectionViewCells, with a reuse identifier, returning the header in this function:
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath. I feel like thats a different question than what was posted though, where you imply you already have a header showing up.